# Forming a subordinate clause after "Du bist dran..."

Tags: difference, standard-german, subordinate-clause

> Du bist heute dran mit dem Kochen, nicht?

Is it wrong to write

> Du bist heute dran zu Kochen, nicht?

I don't understand the use of *mit dem kochen*. Can't I use *zu Kochen* instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's purely an idiomatic difference.  In general, yes, "cooking" will often be translated as an infinitive with *zu*.  In this case, however, there is an established phrasing, *mit etwas dran sein*:

> *X ist mit Y dran* -- "It is X's turn to do Y"

The *mit* is part of the construction.  And as a preposition, it requires a noun, so you have to substantivize the verb: *mit dem Kochen*, or *mit Kochen*.

*X ist dran zu kochen* is grammatically fine, in principle, but sounds just less idiomatic to me (although this could be a regional thing).

Comment: So you can say "zu Kochen", but it's colloquial language?

Comment: It's not really colloquial, it just sounds like a highly unusual phrasing to me. But as I said, this could be due to my Austrian background; it might be totally fine in other German variants. (Same for the questioning _nicht_ suffix. I'd never say that, but at least I know that it's idiomatic in some speaker communities.)

Comment: ok, thanks for your help

Comment: OTOH, _dran sein_ is itself less formal, than, e.g., _an der Reihe sein_, where _zu_ is entirely appropriate.

Comment: "zu Kochen" is wrong capitalization, it must be "zu kochen" because an infinitive after "zu" is still a verb, whereas in "mit dem Kochen" the infinitive has become a noun.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but to me, "X ist dran zu kochen" almost sounds like "X ist dran zum gekocht werden". So "X will be cooked", and not "X will cook".

Comment: @EricDuminil "X will be cooked" would be more like "X wird gekocht" or in this case "X ist dran gekocht zu werden". However, "kochen" could mean "boil" as well, so "X ist dran zu kochen." could mean, "It is X's turn to boil" or "... to be boiling"

Comment: The most idiomatic version IMHO would be "... dran mit kochen", without the "dem".

Answer (score 1):

*Dran sein* is a set phrase similar to *an der Reihe sein, an die Reihe kommen*<sup>[1](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Reihe#d-1-5)</sup>; *drankommen*<sup>[2](https://www.dwds.de/wb/drankommen#d-1-1)</sup>. While both English and German allow the use of an infinitival clause to express what it is a person's turn to do, this happens less frequently in German and the preposition *mit* is preferred.

> Man ist noch nicht dran mit Sterben, wenn man 15, 16 oder 17 ist.<sup>[3](https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=dran+mit+Sterben&corpus=public)</sup>
> *It's not your turn to die when your 15, 16 or 17.*

> Er rennt zum Podium, obwohl er nicht dran ist zu sprechen.<sup>[4](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/politik/polen-wenn-es-noetig-ist-gehe-ich-jeden-tag-auf-die-strasse-1.3596577-3)</sup>
> *He runs to the podium, although it is not his turn to speak*.

I find the second example quite poor and would have called it unidiomatic if the source wasn't a newspaper. Personally, I feel that the reason for *mit* being preferred lies in the fact that *dran sein* with an infinitival clause is used in other senses.

> Er war drauf und dran (*or* nahe dran), zu sterben.
> *He was about to die*.

> Ich bin grade dran, den Bewerbungsbogen auszufüllen.<sup>[5](https://www.bundeswehrforum.de/forum/index.php?topic=28095.0)</sup>
> *I'm in the process of filling out the application form*.

The last example is a colloquial way of expressing progressive aspect, where *dran* is used as a synonym for *dabei*.